# EmberJS: Property Scopes in an ArrayController?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

this is probably a grossly simple question to answer, so I apologize if I am cluttering this forum in advance.

I am displaying a list of items that share the same model and controller.
I made these items editable via a `<button {{ action 'edit' }}>` next to each item which toggles a boolean value of a property "isEditable" in the controller.
However clicking this button causes all items in the list to become editable because they all share the controller property "isEditable".  The desired effect is to make a single item editable at a time instead of all items at once.

A simplified version of my template looks like this:

```
{{#if isEditing}}
      <p>{{input type="text" value=title}}</p>
      <button {{action 'doneEditing'}}>Done</button>
{{else}}
      <span class="title">{{title}}</span>
      <button  {{action 'edit'}}><span class="edit"</span></button>
{{/if}}
```

and the controller looks like this

```
App.ItemController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
isEditing : false,
actions : {
    edit : function(){
        this.set('isEditing', true);
    },
    doneEditing : function(){
        this.set('isEditing', false);
    },
}
```

});

Anybody know how to accomplish this?  Is it because each item shares the "isEditable" property? If so, how do I get around this?  I don't want to put this into the model because it's purely a display thing, even though I know I can get it to work doing that.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the controller lookup within an `{{#each}}` block will be the controller of the template where the `{{#each}}` was used. If each item needs to be presented by a custom controller (to hold it's own state for example) you can provide a `itemController` option which references a controller by lookup name. Each item in the loop will be then wrapped in an instance of this controller and the item itself will be set to the content property of that controller.

So, I assume you are displaying the list of items using the `{{#each}}` helper. Therefore you can specify an `itemController` in the `{{#each}}` helper to hold the `isEditable` state on a per item basis. This would look something like this:

```
{{#each item in controller itemController="item"}}
  ...
{{/each}}
```

Moreover you should define the defined `itemController` of type `Ember.ObjectController` like:

```
App.ItemController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  isEditing : false,
  actions : {
    edit : function(){
      this.set('isEditing', true);
    },
    doneEditing : function(){
      this.set('isEditing', false);
    },
  }
});
```

And for the list you should then have an `App.ItemsController` of type `Ember.ArrayController`:

```
App.ItemsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({});
```

See here for more info on the mentioned itemController support for the `{{#each}}` helper: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_each

Hope it helps.

Comment: Boom. thanks for answering my question so succinctly.  Huge help. Great success!